# What is causing a UnicodeDecodeError when trying to read a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to execute this code snippet in python 3.8

```
 def load_rightprob(self, rightprob_file):
        ''' dictionary with # people keys with # actions  '''
        rightProb = {}
        for line in open(rightprob_file):
            items = line.strip().split("\t")
            if len(items) != len(self.action_qid_dict) + 1:
                continue
            pid = int(items[0])
```

but I get this error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

I tried `for line in open(rightprob_file, **'rb'**):` instead but I get challenges on the following line with this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Can somebody please suggest how to fix this? I am reading from a .txt file where each line is an ID, followed by 377 columns representing probability values associated with this ID

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: @tripleee a value of `FF` in byte 0 means it's 99% likely to be a [BOM for UTF-16 little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16).

Answer (score 1):

It's very unusual for a text file to start with `0xff`.  Because of that, it's sometimes placed deliberately at the start of the file as part of a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) for Unicode, particularly on Windows.  As you can see in the table in the link, only two Unicode encodings have a BOM that starts with `0xff`: UTF-16 or UTF-32, both little endian.  Of the two UTF-16 is far more commonly encountered.

So open your file like this:

```
with open(rightprob_file, 'r', encoding='utf_16_le') as f:
    for line in f:
```

I added the `with` so that the file would be automatically closed when you're done, that was a bug in your original code.

The first character read from the file will be `u'\ufeff'` and can be thrown away or otherwise ignored.